# Editing exising file in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to load an existing file and append some data, save it back. Tried following in SuiteScript 2.0. But following code still gives me old file content ( only first line when it was created !). Whats wrong?

---

```
var fileObj = file.load({
                          id:'SuiteScripts/MergeVendorResults/'+'MergeResult_'+recordId+'.txt'
                    });

                    var oldFileContents = fileObj.getContents();
                    log.debug("Existing file contents","Old File Contents -> "+oldFileContents);
                    fileObj.contents = oldFileContents + "\n"+ fileContents;
                    var id = fileObj.save();
                    fileObj = file.load({
                            id: id
                    });
                    log.debug("Existing file replaced with contents","File Contents -> "+fileObj.getContents());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a whole new file object with the concatenated contents and the original file's name and folderId. Then when you save it'll overwrite the original file.